# diff between two hijri dates (in days) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, hijri

I want to calculate the difference in days between two hijri dates, is that possible in Laravel? i tried this code but it is not working:

```
<?php $diff=date_diff("1438/01/01","1439/01/01"); echo $diff->format("%R%a days"); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As I researched more about Hijri Calender, I found that it has only 354 or 355 days.. So you can take of that by subtracting 10 days. I'll be looking for more consistent solution.

Try this.. More about [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php
$startDate = new DateTime('1438/01/01');
$endDate = new DateTime('1439/01/01');

echo ($startDate->diff($endDate))->format("%R%a");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

then add this in your code.

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse('1438/01/01);
$endDate   = Carbon::parse('1439/01/01);
$dateDiff = $startDate->diff($endDate)->format("%a");

echo $dateDiff;
```

Comment: the result was inaccurate